# Python: Counting Groups of Items in a List

Tags: python, list, function, count

I am working on learning Python via Codecademy and I am struggling to figure out why I am getting a return of 1 when I run this query. Note: I know I could do a sequence.count(item) but I am trying to do this without the count function. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def count(sequence, item):
    rep = int(0)
    for item in sequence:
        if item in sequence:
            rep += 1
        else:
            rep = 0
    return rep

print count([1], 7)
```

Comment: Are you sure it should return `1`? for `count([1],7)`?

Comment: `for item in sequence` and `if item in sequence`? `item` is always in `sequence`. Use another variable's name.

Comment: It shouldn't return 1 but it does. If it looks at the sequence given, and cannot find a 7, I would expect a 0. No?

Comment: Trying it now. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @gnibbler! That did it. I'll mark that solution down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you confused yourself by using "item" to refer to two different things. I changed the loop variable to `i`.

```
def count(sequence, item):
    rep = 0
    for i in sequence:
        if i == item:
            rep += 1
    return rep

print count([1], 7)
```

Also, you probably don't want to keep setting rep to `0`

Comment: If I don't set rep to 0, what would you recommend I set it to?

Comment: You should set it to zero at the start, but don't reset it to zero every time you hit something in the sequence that isn't equal to item - unless your function is doing something quite different to the usual meaning of counting.

Answer (score 1):

Corrected function:

```
def count(sequence, item):
    rep = 0
    for i in sequence:
        if i == item:
            rep += 1
    return rep
```

Regarding these lines:

```
for item in sequence:
    if item in sequence:
```

When you input `[1]` into the function, it goes:

- `for item in sequence`(first and only item is `1`)
- `if item is in sequence`( if `1` is in the sequence... which it is)
- then `rep += 1`, hence 1 is returned

`for item in sequence` means for each `item` in the `sequence`, do something.
In your case you are merely confirming that the item is indeed in the sequence.
You are in fact never even using or considering the `7` you input.